# How can I match numbers with expressions?

Tags: machine-learning

Let's say I have the number 123.45 and the expression *one hundred twenty-three and forty-five* cents.

Can I develop AI to identify these two values as a match? If I can, how should I do that?

Comment: Machine learning is **massive** overkill. Just convert the numbers to word: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504350/how-to-convert-numbers-to-words-in-python